# Regression for the dependent variable values given as intervals

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, ordinal-data

What are optimal methods to find regression coefficients (I need many variable linear regression) when the information about values of the dependent variable is given in form of intervals?

Specifically, each case of my data contains one of the following entries for the dependent variable:
(a) it is 0; (b) it is between 0 and 1; (c) it is between 1 and 2; (d) it is larger than 2.

Comment: The methods depend on what the interval endpoints mean.  In particular, if the endpoints are (a) confidence limits, (b) prediction limits, (c) predetermined cutoffs, (d) cutoffs determined from related data, or (e) guesses made by "experts," the methods will differ dramatically.  Please, then, explain the meaning of your limits.

Comment: @whuber It is simply the only information I have. It is a question, how much time during the day does a person spend on certain activity. The answer is multiple choice: no time, less than a hour, between hour and two, and more than two hours a day.